# React Js input type="number" not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

```
<Form.Input
    type="number"
    pattern="[1-9]"
    disabled={renderDisableInput(
        this.state.user.role
    )}
    placeholder="Phone"
    required={true}
    value={this.state.phone}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    name="phone"
/>
```

In the above code still working good in the Chrome browser, and then coming to firefox the `type="number"` didn't support.

The input field allows all type of text keywords. what is the error in my code?

Comment: Firefox does support <input type="number">. Is something rendered at all, or are you getting errors in your console? It is hard to tell what <Form.Input /> returns

Comment: Firefox has supported `<input type="number">` since version 23. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try out b changing your pattern ,

```
                          <Form.Input
                            type="number"
                            pattern="/[0-9]+/"
                            disabled={renderDisableInput(
                              this.state.user.role
                            )}
                            placeholder="Phone"
                            required={true}
                            value={this.state.phone}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            name="phone"
                          />
```

Comment: still allowing alfa-numeric

Answer (score -1):

In the below sample, you can prevent characters.

```
import { includes } from 'lodash';
const alphabets = [
'a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','l', 'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
'u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D', 'F','G','H','I','J',
'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
];

    return (
        <input
        type="number"
        value={value}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (includes(alphabets, e.key)) {
            e.preventDefault();
          } 
        }}
      />
)
```